# Laravel Contact Template error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it any way to show Error message automatically? Like it is in CodeIgniter?
I have a contact form, and if it's validation error i'm doing:

```
          return Redirect::to('/support/contact')
         ->with('message', 'Feedback must contain more than 5 characters. Try Again.');
```

My rules and my fields:

```
        $rules = array (
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required|min:5'
    );
```

Is it any way to make auto messages according my fields?

My Controller:

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Mail;
use Redirect;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
public function getContactUsForm(){

        $data = \Input::all();

        $rules = array (
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|min:5'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make ($data, $rules);

        if ($validator -> passes()){
           Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($bodyMessage) use ($data)
            {
                $bodyMessage->from($data['email'] , $data['first_name']);



     $bodyMessage->to('hera@22mail.com', 'He')->subject(' Contact Form');

                });
       return Redirect::to('/support/contact')
        ->with('message', 'Your message has been sent. Thank You!');


             }else{
            return Redirect::to('/support/contact')
             ->with('message', 'Feedback must contain more than 5 characters. Try Again.');

         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Yes there is but how you define the message depends how you are applying the rules. Are you using the controller `$this->validate()` method, are you using form request validation or are you manually creating your own validator instance? Please show more code.

Comment: @jfadich posted my controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally easy to do.

One approach is to change your $validator to use a another array of messages:

Example:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'first_name'            => 'required',
            'email'                 => 'required|email',
            'message'               => 'required|min:5'
        ],
        [
            'first_name.required'     => 'First Name is required',
            'email.required'          => 'Email is Required.',
            'email.email'             => 'Not a valid email',
            'message.max'             => 'Message is Required.',
            'message.min'             => 'Message must me at least 5 characters.',
        ]
    );
```

Another approach would be to pass the messages as a third arguement

```
$messages = [

            'first_name.required'     => 'First Name is required',
            'email.required'          => 'Email is Required.',
            'email.email'             => 'Not a valid email',
            'message.max'             => 'Message is Required.',
            'message.min'             => 'Message must me at least 5 characters.',

]

$validator = Validator::make ($data, $rules, $messages);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-error-messages

You may also want to check on the validator failing instead of success with something like the following in place of of your if/else and then have the 'happy path' at the bottom of the method.

```
    if ($validator->fails()) {

        // Or do custom action here with $request, $validator

        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
```